# Table View Cell is Blank Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uitableview, swift

My UITableView data source and delegate are not connected to any file. If this is the problem, would someone tell me how to connect them. If not, here is my code.

My File containing the struct info:

```
 struct PreviousApps {
    var name : String
    var description : String
    var filename : String
}
```

And this is my code in my TableViewController:

```
    import UIKit

class PreviousProjectsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


    var apps = [PreviousApps]()





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var PreviousApp = PreviousApps(name: "Gecko Catch", description: "DESCRIPTION", filename: "geckocatch.png")
        apps.append(PreviousApp)

        PreviousApp = PreviousApps(name: "Flappy Timothy", description: "DESCRIPTION", filename: "flappytimothy.png")
        apps.append(PreviousApp)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        var currentApp = apps[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = currentApp.name
        return cell
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return apps.count
    }
}
```

I am new to Swift and any help would be appreciated. If i'm not being specific enough, tell me and I will try to provide you with more info.

Thanks,
Beck

Comment: Do you use a storyboard and drag a tableviewcontroller?

Comment: "If this is the problem" -- seriously?? SO is not a substitute for reading the documentation.

Comment: @rdelmar I have read the documentation and know about outlets, I just didn't know how to connect the delegate or data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using storyboard to set up your tableviewcontroller:

1. Set PreviousProjectsVC as the class for the table view controller using identity inspector (at right panel in Xcode)
2. Click on the "Show document outline" at the bottom-left corner in storyboard
3. Select the TableView from the outline and control + drag from there to the yellow icon at the top of the table view controller scene in storyboard
4. Select delegate and datasource from the menu displayed

To set the delegate and datasource from the code, create an outlet for the TableView and set tableView.delegate = self and tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: When I tried this I got "thread 1: signal SIGABRT". I checked for any deleted outlets. Do you know why this is happening

Comment: Were you able to solve the "thread 1: signal SIGABRT" problem? here is a link that might be of some help in figuring out the problem : https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/thread-1-signal-sigabrt-at-the-end

Comment: @munib.rahim I ended up fixing the problem and it worked. Thank you for your help.